# Solving differential equation $y y' = x^2 y + (a^2 - 1) x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the differential equation for $y=y(x)$:
$$
y y' = x^2 y + (a^2 - 1) x .
$$
I know that this the Abel equation of second kind. But, I could not solve it analytically. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Who said it is easy to solve? It is a nonlinear ODE, in general, these are not analytically tractable.

Comment: @Gregory Mathematica!

Comment: Ok, what did Mathematica say the answer was?

Comment: @Gregory Oh no! Sorry! Mathematica cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by $y,$ you get

$$y^\prime = x^2 + (a^2-1)x/y.$$

Solve the homogeneous part (easy), then use indetermined coefficients.

Comment: This is a nonlinear equation. I don't think you can split your solution $y$ into a homogeneous and non-homogeneous part and then just add them. I fail to see how this helps.

Comment: @Gregory Thanks, good to know!